# SQL connections to java applications

Tags: connectivity, sql-server-2000, java, connection-pooling, dynamic-ports

I have an MSSQLServer2000 database that seems to have been working just fine until today. The DB connects to a java application on a remote server that passes the database data (login credentials, various records in tables) to other system elements in this network. This java application needs to connect to the DB for the other systems to do their job.

As far as I can tell there should be no issues with connectivity between this java application and the DB. `netstat -an` shows an ESTABLISHED connection between both IPs on port 1433, I am able to authtenicate on the SQL server locally with the credentials provided to the java application. There are no apparent errors in the server event viewer logs, nor have there been any changes to the system I am aware of....and yet the application fails to connect.

The application needs the following information in its connection pool fields to connect to the DB: Instance (which I queried with `SELECT @@servicename`) Schema Owner (which i queried with `SELECT schema_name, schema_owner FROM information_schema.schemata`) and the login user and password (which I know to be accurate and can login in via SQL Enterprise Manager)

1. Is there anything else I should be looking out for?
2. are those the correct queries to collect the information I needed? it seems the Instance is MSSQLSERVER and the schema owner dbo.

I am very new and green to SQL, not a DBA or software guy by any stretch. I have not ruled out reinstalling the java app. I have checked that TCP/IP port 1433 is enabled (as well as Named Pipes in the SQL Server Network Utility), restarted SQL services, and for good measure rebooted both servers. and this java app remains unable to connect to the server.

edit: there was one thing I noticed in the SQL logs. a message about remote access set from 1 to 0? and I ran `EXEC sp_configure 'remote access', 1;` that didnt seem to have any effect on letting me get connected.

edit #2: 1) OS is MS Server 2000. 2) Yes I can. I have another serer running SQL 2008 on MS Server 2008 and I can connect remotely from that SQL Server to this one, using the same credentials I supply to the java application. 3) no recent security updates to my knowledge.

thanks for any input!

Comment: Could you update your question with the answers to these items: (1) which operating system is SQL Server running on? (2) are you able to connect externally with SSMS? (3) have there been any security updates applied to any of the systems — or their hosts — recently?

Comment: Sounds like the issue is stemming from outside your SQL Server instance, perhaps either directly with the application itself (if it's easy enough to reinstall, I'd start there), or a change to the systems the database and/or the application runs on, as matigo mentions above.

Comment: After running `EXEC sp_configure 'remote access', 1;` did you run the `RECONFIGURE` command as well? You'll need to run a `RECONFIGURE` in order for the configuration change to be activated.

Comment: yep. sorry should have included that.